# How can I optimize this code??(python)

Tags: python, optimization

this is problem 5 of Project Euler website.

```
def divisable_into_1to20(num):
    for i in range(11,21):
        if num % i != 0:
        return False
    return True 

for i in range(2520,10000000000):
    if divisable_into_1to20(i):
        print(i)
        break
```

It takes 140 seconds

Comment: What is the expected output of this problem?

Comment: They;re presumably expecting you to think this through mathematically, and then just work out and multiply the factors, not check every number one by one.

Comment: For example: the smallest number divisible by 1, 2, and 3 is `1*2*3=6`. The smallest number divisible by 1, 2, 3, and 4 is not 24, but 12,. Why? Because the 4 already takes care of the 2 (and the 1 was already taken care of), so it's `3*4` If you can figure out how to explain that logic to a 5-year-old, then you can turn that logic into code, and you can get the least common multiple of the first 20 numbers.

Comment: If this code runs in such a short time (140 seconds) and gives the correct answer, you have access to the ProjectEuler discussion page for this problem. There you can see other approaches, including some in Python. Why is that not suitable for you? ProjectEuler explicitly says that you should not seek for help in sites like this one.

Comment: As a projecteuler hobbyist myself I must to say I really dislike people that post projecteuler answers (unoptimal or optimal) on other sites that are not the projecteuler forum, by doing so you guys not only go against the projecteuler "rules" but you're also potentially stealing some fun for people who haven't found the answers... Of course, people have the choice of not looking at... but even so, I think it's just wrong, so here we go, a downvote to your question from me :) . Please make sure you read [https://projecteuler.net/about](https://projecteuler.net/about) carefully.

Answer (score 1):

Let's say that you want your code to be fast. My suggestion is to use Cython. A quick search for its [documentation](https://cython.readthedocs.io/en/latest/src/quickstart/cythonize.html) can tell you many tricks to highly optimize code: declare types, parallellize, ... One example in a Jupyter Notebook could be:

```
    %%cython
    # distutils: language = c++
    cimport cython
    from libcpp cimport bool

    @cython.cdivision(True)
    cdef inline bool divisable_into_1to20(int num):
        cdef int i, a=11, b=21
        for i in range(a,b):
            if cython.cmod(num,i):
                return False
        return True 

    cpdef problem_5_proj_euler():
        cdef int num, k1=2520, k2=10000000000
        for num in range(k1,k2):
            if divisable_into_1to20(num):
                return num
```

The **original solution** took **130 seconds** in my laptop. This one takes **900ms**!

## Bonus: parallelize!

Someone might say: Hey! for sure if we parallelize we will get even better performance!. So I tried:

```
    %%cython
    # distutils: language = c++
    cimport cython
    from cython.parallel import prange
    from libcpp cimport bool

    @cython.cdivision(True)
    cdef inline bool divisable_into_1to20(int num) nogil:
        cdef int i, a=11, b=21
        for i in range(a,b):
            if cython.cmod(num,i):
                return False
        return True 

    cpdef problem_5_proj_euler():
        cdef int final_num, num, k1=2520, k2=10000000000
        for num in prange(k1,k2, nogil=True):
            if divisable_into_1to20(num):
                break
        return num
```

surprisingly enough, this solution takes **1.9seconds**, twice as slow! Given the small size of the task, parallelizing causes an overhead in creating the threads and running the pieces of code.

Comment: It appears that you have answered your own question. There is nothing quite like that "Aha!" moment when you finally beat a problem which you have been working on for some time. It is often through the best of intentions in wishing to share our insights so that others can enjoy that moment too. Sadly, however, that will not be the case for your readers. Real learning is an active process and seeing how it is done is a long way from experiencing that epiphany of discovery. Please do not deny others what you have so richly valued yourself.

Comment: I'll take back my downvote because now the answer seems to focus on optimizing a piece of code... Still, I think threads like this one are just wrong and go against [projecteuler](https://projecteuler.net/about) nature, anyway... just saying :/

Answer (score -1):

The (almost) fastest solution is the following:

```
print(5*7*9*11*13*16*17*19)
```

It is easy to see that a number is divisible with each of the numbers between 2 and 20 if and only if it is a multiple of this one.